# Golang date parsing

Tags: date, parsing, go

I have a string like this

`Fri, 3 Mar 2017 13:08:54 +0100`

I need to convert this `string` in a `time.Time` object in **Golang**.

The layout seems to be `RFC1123Z` so I have try in this way

`(RFC1123Z = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700" // RFC1123 with numeric zone)`

```
d := "Thu, 2 Mar 2017 10:44:13 +0100"
da, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC1123Z, d)
fmt.Println(da)
```

But I get this:

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

What is wrong?

Comment: don't ignore errors.... then you'll know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it to be `time.RFC1123Z` the day must be `02` not `2`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    d := "Thu, 02 Mar 2017 10:44:13 +0100"
    da, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC1123Z, d)
    fmt.Println(da)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/JFtErfZTtk

If you cannot change the source time string you can alternatively parse it with the `Mon, 2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700` format:

```
da, _ := time.Parse("Mon, 2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700", d)
```

References:

- https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants

Comment: Thanks @zerkms but I'm using a lib that return a string like this "Fri, 3 Mar 2017 13:08:54 +0100". So how can I parse it?

Comment: @matiux Use the `Mon, 2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700` parsing format instead?

Comment: @matiux you need to check the answer then

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func ParseRFC1123Z(date string) (t time.Time, err error) {
    t, err = time.Parse(time.RFC1123Z, date)
    errOriginal := err
    if err != nil {
        t, err = time.Parse("Mon, 2 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700", date)
    }
    if err != nil {
        err = errOriginal
    }
    return 
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/LwYRTBsM4KU